# Unable to read 64 bit registry key on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, registry, uac

I'm having an issue with the following bit of code that attempts to read a registry key but fails. The specific error is: "*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*." The code I'm using is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace UDTLibrary
{
    public class NotificationBar
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get User Info
            string sSource;
            string sLog;

            sSource = "TestCSFileSysWatcher";
            sLog = "Application";

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);

            EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "NotificationBar.Main start");

            WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            if (!principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "NotificationBar.Main - non-Administrator");
            }
            else
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "NotificationBar.Main Administrator");
            }

            NotificationBar p1 = new NotificationBar();
            string prName = null;
            int value = 0;
            if (args == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Attempt to run NotificationBar with no arguments supplied.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (args.Length != 2)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Wrong number of arguments supplied.");
                }
                else
                {
                    prName = args[0];
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
                }
            }

            RegistryKey currentUser = null;
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                currentUser = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
            }
            else
            {
                currentUser = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
            }
            RegistryKey myKey = currentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify", true);
            byte[] all = (byte[])myKey.GetValue("IconStreams"); //here is where the code fails
            byte[] allwithoutheader = new byte[all.Length - 20];
            byte[] header = new byte[20];
```

Some facts about my environment:

- This is a 32-bit app that I'm running on Windows 7 (with UAC enabled - no, I can't turn it off). However, I am reading from the 64-bit view of the registry (as seen in the code above - I've confirmed that RegistryView.Registry64 is being selected)
- The code is running with Administrative rights. I've confirmed this through the code above that checks WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator - the log writes the "Administrator" line and not the "non-Administrator" line
- I've tried changing the code to read a string rather than a byte, and also to read from a different location (in HKLM rather than HKCU) with no success.

Am I missing something obvious here? Any advice you can give would be much appreciated. If there's anything else you need to troubleshoot, just let me know.

Comment: Look at the inner exception data probably currentKey or myKey is null

Comment: Thanks - I just checked and myKey is indeed null (although currentUser isn't). But I've confirmed that the key HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify does in fact exist. Why would my code not be able to see it?

Comment: Is your current user HKCU?

Comment: I had assumed that it was. How can I confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to open a key and there is no such key you'll get null.
try recreating the key like this:

```
if (mykey == null)
{
   key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"CurrentVersion\TrayNotify");
}
```

now go to registry using ***regedit*** command and find you sub key "CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" you'll see the difference between what you created and what you were looking for..

if you would like to check your current user, run command line and then enter

```
 echo %username%
```